# creating a gradual 'frequency unification' effect (or illusion)

Tags: sound-effects, signal-processing, texture

hello,

i'm working on material with rather rich frequency range. now i've reached a point in the process where i need to design a gradual transparent effect which would make this wide-ranging sonic material sound like its narrowing down, unifying, and perceptibly coming together into a single thick (high) tone/texture. i'm trying to think how to go about creating such effect and wanted to ask for some advice/suggestions from people in this vibrant community :)

thanks
K.

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head something like GRM Tools Bandpass comes to mind. Anything where you have the ability to automate frequency bands to tighten in those areas you require might work? I'm sure you could get decent results with stock Eqs and DAW automation though...

Comment: On the topic of GRM Tools, maybe the GRM Reson would help you get there too.

Answer (score 1):

By your description, an approach I'd probably try would be one of pitch and harmony as opposed to other effects. Pitch-bending sounds all together to start dissonant but lock together in harmonies and dense overtones (perhaps pitched to major or minor key, depending on the emotional effect you need to achieve). You can also combine that with filtering to eliminate the odd inharmonic tone, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Spatial automation, wet/dry reverb automation, reversed layers